# javax.validation.Validation multiple instantiation Vs Reusing single Validator instance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entities

I am using javax.validation.Validation to validate jpa entities. I am always validating against the same Entities.

I would like to know if it is better to use one Validator for all validations or to instantiate a new Validator each time I validate.

As well, how expensive in terms of computation is it for me to instantiate a new validator each time I would like to use it?

Option1: instantiate new validator for each validation.

```
public class Validator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        //Validation1
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Entity entityToValidate  = new Entity();
        entityToValidate.setEmail("NOT_A_VALID_EMAIL@@@tomanyat.com");
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations =             validator.validate(entityToValidate);





        //Validation2 (Note that validator has been created yet a second time !! )
        Validator validator2 = factory.getValidator();

        Entity entityToValidate2  = new Entity();        
         entityToValidate.setEmail("NOT_A_VALID_EMAIL@@@tomanyat.com");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations2 = validator2.validate(entityToValidate);



    }


}
```

Option2: single validator for all validations.

```
public class Validator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Validator created only once
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(); 
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();


        //Validation #1
        Entity entityToValidate  = new Entity();
        entityToValidate.setEmail("NOT_A_VALID_EMAIL@@@tomanyat.com");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entityToValidate);




        //Validation #2     
        Entity entityToValidate2  = new Entity();
        entityToValidate.setEmail("NOT_A_VALID_EMAIL@@@tomanyat.com");


        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations2 = validator .validate(entityToValidate);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note how the `Validator` javadoc states

> Validates bean instances. Implementations of this interface must be
>   thread-safe.

As such a `Validator` shouldn't really contain state, unless that state is also thread-safe. Therefore, you shouldn't need to create a new `Validator` instance, just re-use the same one, depending on the types obviously.

> As well, how expensive in terms of computation is it for me to
>   instantiate a new validator each time I would like to use it?

This depends on your `Validator`. But the instantiation (creating but not initializing the object) itself is almost completely negligible, especially when you consider all the processing that a JPA implementation performs.

Answer (score 1):

> re-use the same one, depending on the types obviously.

The selected answer does not explain why reusing a validator should depend on the type of the objects being validated. If thread-safety is guaranteed, I don't see any limits on how it should be used. The api does not specify such a limit.